# Use libCurl with Bluecoat cookie proxy

Tags: cookies, proxy, libcurl

I am trying to connect through a Bluecoat proxy which uses a cookie during the proxy authentication.

I have been completely unable to find a combination of CURLOPT_ settings that will get CURL to present the cookie during proxy authentication.

So: the proxy responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: close
Set-Cookie: BCSI-CS-EDD688431754D715=2; Path=/
Connection: close
Content-Length: 825
```

But curl does not present the cookie in subsequent authentication attempts, no matter what I set for CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE or CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.

NOTE: I am also using (because I must)

```
CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE = CURLPROXY_HTTP
CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH = CURLAUTH_ANY
CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL = 1
CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY = 1
```

Is it reasonable to expect CURL to present a cookie with a Proxy-Authorization request?

I am using curl_easy_*, would moving to the multi interface help?

Finally, I am building with 7.19.7

Comment: libcurl at least has no intended limitation for this scenario

Comment: Daniel! I am honored.
Could you give me a clue as to how to get libcurl to present a cookie when it is responding to a 407? I even tried useing CURLOPT_COOKIE to set one explicitly, and it still was not part of the authentication request.

Comment: Just to make sure I wasn't hallucinating, I just now wrote up a test cases that does something similar to your use case here and it works fine. See https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/tests/data/test1331

Comment: What you posted gives me real hope.  I already saw a couple of days ago a thread on the libcurl mailing list about using the curl command line to deal with a bluecoat proxy.  I know that curl can do it.  What I am looking for is the CURLOPT_ equivalents for using the library. We are creating a tunnel using CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL  and CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY so our conversation with the server is slightly different possibly?  Could that be the problem?

Comment: Aha! Yes that is indeed the explanation. The CONNECT thing is done a bit separately in the code and... whatdoyouknow? There's no cookie handling done there! I consider it a bug. Can't promise a swift fix though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CONNECT request is done a bit separately in the code than the "regular" requests and it seems there's no cookie handling done there! I consider it a libcurl bug.

(This is my comment from above, turned into a proper answer.)

Comment: Well that actually works for me! I can get on with my life!  (AND recommend that the client disable the cookie surrogate on their proxy!) Thanks again! ;}D

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a tunnel through a Blue Coat Proxy. But my advice is not to use a network with the Blue Coat Proxy. In a free country it should not be a problem to buy a SIM card and use a mobile network instead.

Read more at https://bluecoatproxy.wordpress.com

Comment: Does this address your question? https://kb.bluecoat.com/index?page=content&id=FAQ2016&actp=LIST